# Does 'git remote add' create just aliases for the same repository?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

When I create a new project in my gitlab, I get a default name `origin` for the repository in the server.
Then I may use `git remote add [name] [url]` to create several so-called remote repositories. If I type `git remote`, I just get something followed:

```
$ git remote
 
name1 
name2
origin
```

Actually I can only see one repository namely the project in my gitlab, where are the others? So after I use `git push name1`, does it `push` to all of the remote repositories or just `push` to the `origin`? I don't see any difference compared to the way without adding names.

Comment: `git push` pushes to `origin` by default. Try `git remote -v` to get more information about the available repositories. The full picture is revealed in `.git/config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git remote add [name] [url]` adds the `name` as an alias for the `url` **in the current local repository**. The alias is named "a remote" (noun). No distant (I have to use the word "distant" to avoid using "remote") server is contacted, even less no distant repositories are created.

> after I use `git push name1`, does it push to all of the remote repositories or just push to the `origin`?

The syntax is

```
git push [remote [ref]]
```

That is, you can do `git push` (will push the default refs to the default remote; depends on configuration, but usually it pushes the current branch to its upstream remote, usually `origin`); or you can do `git push name1` naming the remote explicitly; or you can do `git push name1 master` naming the remote and the branch.

There is no builtin way to push to multiple remotes but it's possible with additional command line tools.